# Git clone through http:// does not clone all tags

Tags: git, http, ssh, tags, clone

When I do a `git clone http://<url-to-my-repo>/repo.git`, not all of the tags of the repository are copied. When I clone through `ssh://`, I *do not* have this issue.

I have no clue how this is possible. I made sure that all files of the bare repo on the server are accessible for the `_www` user who runs the apache process that serves the files.

### On the server

#### Tags

```
bash-3.2# git tag
1.9
1.9.1
1.9.2
1.9.3
1.9.4
1.9.5
2.0
2.1
2.1.1
2.1.2
2.2
2.2.1
2.2.2
2.2.3
2.2.4
2.3
2.3.1
2.3.2
2.4.0
2.4.1
2.4.2
2.4.3
2.4.4
```

#### File permissions of the repo

```
bash-3.2# ls -alh
total 24
drwxr-x---   10 git  _www    340B Dec  3 12:12 .
drwxr-xr-x    9 git  staff   306B Feb  1 16:46 ..
-rwxrwxrwx    1 git  _www     23B Dec  3 12:12 HEAD
drwxrwxrwx    2 git  _www     68B Dec  3 12:12 branches
-rwxrwxrwx    1 git  _www    112B Dec  3 12:12 config
-rwxrwxrwx    1 git  _www     73B Dec  3 12:12 description
drwxrwxrwx   10 git  _www    340B Dec  3 12:12 hooks
drwxrwxrwx    4 git  _www    136B Jan  8 23:19 info
drwxrwxrwx  220 git  _www    7.3K Feb  1 23:14 objects
drwxrwxrwx    4 git  _www    136B Dec  3 12:12 refs
```

### When cloning

#### through `http://`

```
/Library/WebServer/TrinchHosts/www master $ git tag
1.9
1.9.1
1.9.2
1.9.3
1.9.4
1.9.5
2.0
2.1
2.1.1
2.1.2
2.2
2.2.1
2.2.2
2.2.3
2.2.4
2.3
2.3.1
2.3.2
2.4.0
2.4.1
2.4.2
```

#### through `ssh://`

```
/Library/WebServer/TrinchHosts/www master $ git tag
1.9
1.9.1
1.9.2
1.9.3
1.9.4
1.9.5
2.0
2.1
2.1.1
2.1.2
2.2
2.2.1
2.2.2
2.2.3
2.2.4
2.3
2.3.1
2.3.2
2.4.0
2.4.1
2.4.2
2.4.3
2.4.4
```

I have no idea why the `2.4.3` and `2.4.4` tags are not copied when I clone the repo through `http://`

Any help or ideas? What could be the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that on your server repository you have enabled the post-update hook which calls update-server-info to record some details that can be missed by the http dumb server. See [the manual page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-server-info.html) for some details about this.

Comment: Thanks. Running `git update-server-info` fixed the problem. I also added it as a `post-update` hook like you suggested. Works perfectly now... Thanks again!